# Apex chart individual color for each line but no fill

Tags: nuxt.js, apexcharts

I am trying to set a fixed color for each line but as soon as I add the color, the line will automatically also get a fill which I do not want.

I have tried anything I can find on Google but unfortunately without any working solution. Can anyone please help me out?

For each data object I create an object like this:

```
const obj = {
  name: index,
  data: [],
  color: dataTypeColors[i],
}
```

In my chart options I use the fill option to make the fill transparent like this:

```
fill: {
  type: 'solid',
colors: ['transparent'],
}
```

If I do not fill in a color in the data object, it works perfectly. The downside is that Apex decides what line gets what color, and that is not what I want. I want to define the color for each line myself.

As soon as I add the color for the lines, Apex will ignore the "transparent" fill and fill in the background with the color given in the data object.

Does anyone know how I can decide what color each line gets, but without a fill? I also would like to give some, not all, lines a dash instead of a solid line.

Below is an example of the outcome with the above code. I expect a line without a (gradient) fill, but all lines do have fills.

[image]

I tried everything I can find on Google but nothing worked unfortunately. I am using Nuxt 2 and the latest version of Apex charts.

So in short what I want:

1. Give each line individually a custom color
2. Decide for each line individually if the line is solid or dashed
3. Decide for each line individually if the line has a colored or transparent background (gradient)

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays in the following options to target specific series:

1. [`colors` – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/)
2. [`stroke` – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/stroke/)
3. [`fill` – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/fill/)

Take a look at this example:

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series 1',
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }, {
    name: 'Series 2',
    data: [3, 7, 11]
  }, {
    name: 'Series 3',
    data: [30, 22, 10]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    height: 350
  },
  labels: [
    new Date(2023, 0, 1).getTime(),
    new Date(2023, 1, 1).getTime(),
    new Date(2023, 2, 1).getTime()
  ],
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
  // ========================= HERE =========================
  colors: ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'],
  stroke: {
    width: 10,
    dashArray: [10, 0, 3]      
  },
  fill: {
    type: ['gradient', 'solid', 'solid']
  }
  // ==================================================
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts@3.36.2"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```